# MongoDB-Escape dots '.' in map key]

Tags: spring, mongodb

Map key codeofproduct contains dots but no replacement was configured! Make sure map keys don't contain dots in the first place or configure an appropriate replacement!

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Map key foo.bar.key contains dots but no replacement was configured! Make sure map keys don't contain dots in the first place or configure an appropriate replacement!
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.potentiallyEscapeMapKey(MappingMongoConverter.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeMapInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:586)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createMap(MappingMongoConverter.java:517)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:424)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:386)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:373)
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:257)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:373)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:451)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:386)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:373)
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:257)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:373)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:451)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:386)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:373)
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:257)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:373)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:345)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:310)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:859)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:806)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:794)

When we try to insert value, this happens. How can we solve this?

this is my class

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("net.ooo.hepsiburada.**.repository")
@Profile(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)
public class CloudMongoDbConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration  {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudDatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Inject
    private MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory;

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<>();;
        converterList.add(DateToZonedDateTimeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(DateToLocalDateConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(LocalDateToDateConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(DateToLocalDateTimeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converterList.add(LocalDateTimeToDateConverter.INSTANCE);
        return new CustomConversions(converterList);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return mongoDbFactory.getDb().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return mongoDbFactory().getDb().getMongo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using Spring Data MongoDB you get an instance of: `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter` that has `mapKeyDotReplacement` set to null by default - that is why you are getting an exception.

You need to either create your own instance of `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter` or just modify existing instance using its provider setter method:

```
/**
 * Configure the characters dots potentially contained in a {@link Map} shall be replaced with. By default we don't do
 * any translation but rather reject a {@link Map} with keys containing dots causing the conversion for the entire
 * object to fail. If further customization of the translation is needed, have a look at
 * {@link #potentiallyEscapeMapKey(String)} as well as {@link #potentiallyUnescapeMapKey(String)}.
 * 
 * @param mapKeyDotReplacement the mapKeyDotReplacement to set
 */
public void setMapKeyDotReplacement(String mapKeyDotReplacement) {
    this.mapKeyDotReplacement = mapKeyDotReplacement;
}
```

In MongoDB, dot is always treated as a special character so avoiding it will most likely save you some other headache in the future.

EDIT:
To override default `MappingMongoConverter` add the following bean declaration:

```
  @Bean
  public MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter(MongoDbFactory mongoFactory) throws Exception {
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoFactory);
    MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mongoMappingContext);
    mongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement(".");

    return mongoConverter;
  }
```

Comment: Where will i put this modification?

Comment: See this q&a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598595/how-to-customize-mappingmongoconverter-setmapkeydotreplacement-in-spring-boot

Comment: i added my class. inside that class? but how?

Comment: I have added my solution to the link in R4J's comment.

Answer (score 9):

My exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Map key VAT Registration No. contains dots but no replacement was configured! Make sure map keys don't contain dots in the first place or configure an appropriate replacement!
```

Field with a dot at the end: `VAT Registration No.`

This didn't work for me:

```
mongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement(".");
mongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("_"); //this broke enum values for example VALUE_1 -> VALUE.1
```

This works for me:

```
mongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("-DOT")
```

Complete class:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter(MongoDbFactory mongoFactory, MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext) {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoFactory);
        MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mongoMappingContext);
        mongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("-DOT");
        return mongoConverter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For XML configuration following will be useful.

**Note : mongoConverter bean is used for this. It will replace "." in key with "_"**

```
<bean id="mappingContext" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />

<mongo:auditing mapping-context-ref="mappingContext"/>

<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" mongo-ref="mongoClient" dbname="${mongo.dbname}"/>

<bean id ="mongoConverter" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mappingContext"/>
    <property name="mapKeyDotReplacement" value="_"></property>
</bean>

<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" credentials="${mongo.credential}" >
    <mongo:client-options  connections-per-host="50" threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="5000" />
</mongo:mongo-client>

<!-- MongoDB Template -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mongoConverter"/>   
</bean>
```