# Save dots '.' in key as a field in MongoDB using SpringBoot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I have json data where the key contains dots as '123.456' and value as object.

```
  {
        "models": {
            "123.456": [{
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2"
            }]
        }
    }
```

I am getting an mapping exception when trying to save the object in MongoDB as following

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Map key 123.456 contains dots but no replacement was configured!Make sure map keys don't contain dots in the first place or configure an appropriate replacement!
```

Is there any support to save the key as a field containing dots in Spring Mongo?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `MappingMongoConverter` class. It has the `setMapKeyDotReplacement(String mapKeyDotReplacement)` method.

**According to the [Spring-MongoDB Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.html):**

> The `setMapKeyDotReplacement(String mapKeyDotReplacement)`method checks whether the dots are present in a Map or not. If found, then it should be replaced with the character specified.

Example of how to use it:

```
@Component
public class Example {

    @Autowired
    private MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter;

    public void replaceKeyContainingDot() {
      mappingMongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("pass here the character you want to replace the dots with");
    }

}
```

**Note : From [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) :**

> The use of $ and . in field names is not recommended and is not
>   supported by the official MongoDB drivers.

There is a workaround that I found from documentation. You may have to override `potentiallyEscapeMapKey(String source)` and `potentiallyUnescapeMapKey(String source)` methods from `MappingMongoCoverter` class.

**Please refer to this popular SO questions here for more information and better understanding :**

1. **[How to customize MappingMongoConverter (setMapKeyDotReplacement) in Spring-Boot without breaking the auto-configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598595/how-to-customize-mappingmongoconverter-setmapkeydotreplacement-in-spring-boot)**
2. **[MongoDB-Escape dots '.' in map key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785004/mongodb-escape-dots-in-map-key)**

Comment: But I do not want to replace dots instead I would like to save dots as it is and when I used the mongoMappingConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement(".") I am getting Invalid bson field dot exception.

Comment: From mongo db documentation, the use of $ and . in field names is not recommended and is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers.

Comment: Mongo 3.6 allows using dots and dollar signs in field names https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

Comment: @shashank  So, are you using MongoDB 3.6 ?

Comment: @shashank See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name

Comment: @shashank Workaround is there but I'm not sure. Find  a way to override the method `potentiallyEscapeMapKey(String source )`.

Comment: yes I was going through the documentation and thought of trying with this method potentiallyEscapeMapKey(".")