# MongoDB replace dots in Map key

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, dictionary

I want to save a map in MongoDB and get following error:

`Map key My.Key contains dots but no replacement was configured! Make sure map keys don't contain dots in the first place or configure an appropriate replacement!`

I added following bean declaration, but for some reason it makes no difference.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoFactory, MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext) {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoFactory);
        MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mongoMappingContext);
        mongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("-DOT");
        return mongoConverter;
    }
}
```

I am using spring boot version 2.5.2. On another project with spring boot version 2.0.7.RELEASE it is working fine.

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598595/how-to-customize-mappingmongoconverter-setmapkeydotreplacement-in-spring-boot

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785004/mongodb-escape-dots-in-map-key