# MappingMongoConverter setMapKeyDotReplacement dont work

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongo

My code following this link:

[How to customize MappingMongoConverter (setMapKeyDotReplacement) in Spring-Boot without breaking the auto-configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598595/how-to-customize-mappingmongoconverter-setmapkeydotreplacement-in-spring-boot)

```
@Override
@Bean
public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception {
    DefaultDbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(this.mongoDbFactory());
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, this.mongoMappingContext());
    converter.setCustomConversions(this.customConversions());
    converter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("_");
    return converter;
}
```

But if I try parse this JSON, which is Java JSONObject:

```
{
  "Dr.Web category": "known infection source",
  "categories": [
    "parked",
    "uncategorized"
  ]
}
```

This exception always happens.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Map key Dr.Web category contains dots but no replacement was configured! Make sure map keys don't contain dots in the first place or configure an appropriate replacement!
```

This is strange cause setMapKeyDotReplacement is actually set so all dots should be replaced.

**Do you have any ideas why this solution does not work?**

Answer (score 0):

Try including `converter.afterPropertiesSet()` before the return statement.

Comment: I followed: One minor correction: there's no need for you to call mongoConverter.afterPropertiesSet(). The container will call that for you.

However it doesnt work.