# Spring Boot & Mongo: custom MappingMongoConverter doesn't work during DotReplacement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I need to achive dotReplacementKey

I'm using MongoDB with such config:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoTemplateConfig {

@Value("${adserver_mongo_connection_string}")
private String databaseConnectionString;

@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws UnknownHostException {

    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(databaseConnectionString.trim());
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(uri);
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
}

@Bean
public MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter(MongoDbFactory mongoFactory, MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext) throws Exception {
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoFactory);
    MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mongoMappingContext);
    mongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement(".");

    return mongoConverter;
}
}
```

I'm doing upsert as follows:
`mongoTemplate.bulkOps(...).upsert(...)`

but during runtime via debug I found out that **different MappingMongoConverter is used** rather then this that was configured as a @Bean

btw, if @Inject wherever MappingMongoConverter I get proper bean from config with keyDotReplacement="."
but looks like Spring Boot uses another one under the hood

P.S. I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804985/mappingmongoconverter-setmapkeydotreplacement-dont-work) without correct answer, but tried with `mongoConverter.afterPropertiesSet()` and obviously it doesn't work as well

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit ridiculous but the point is that **we should pass this custom mappingMongoConverter into MongoTemplate initialization** :

```
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter) throws UnknownHostException {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this point. It worked after using different options.